# ¿Como usar substring correctamente en c#?

Tags: c#, string, substring

¡Buenas!

Estoy tratando de hacer el ahorcado en C# para afianzar mis conocimientos sobre el uso de Strings. Pero usando el metodo substring me dice que "se sale del indice".

Os dejo el codigo:

```cs
static String changingHiddenWord(String hiddenWord) {
            String changed, firstPart, endPart;
            int len = secretWord.Length-1;
            for (int i=0;i<len;i++) {
                String stri = Char.ToString(secretWord[i]);
                if (stri == letter) {
                     changed = letter;

                     if (i > 0) {
                        firstPart = hiddenWord.Substring(0,(i*2)-1);
                        Console.WriteLine("firstPart: ", firstPart);
                     } else {
                        firstPart = "";
                    }
                    if (i > 0) {
                        endPart = hiddenWord.Substring((i*2)-1,len);
                    } else {
                        endPart = "";
                    }
                    hiddenWord = firstPart + changed + endPart;
                    }
             } return hiddenWord;
      }
```

os pongo en contexto:
hiddenWord tiene el formato "- - - - -"
letter es una letra minúscula
secretWord es una la palabra secreta que intento adivinar, en este caso "fuente".

por tanto cuando introduzco la t hiddenWord deberia ser: "- - - - t -"

Este es el error

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index and length must refer to a location within the string.
>   Parameter name: length
>     at System.String.Substring (System.Int32 startIndex, System.Int32 length) [0x00076] in <8f2c484307284b51944a1a13a14c0266>:0 
>     at ahorcado.ahorcado.changingHiddenWord (System.String hiddenWord) [0x00073] in <84dfe50e1577450cacf5ed8ac60b8b1d>:0

¡Gracias de antemano!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando llama `Substring`, el *index* y *length* debe referir a un posicion valido en la cadena. Significa que no debe ser mayor que la ultima indice en la cadena (`cadena.Length - 1`).
Una metoda para comprobar si el `substring` conseguir lo que intenta es depurar el codigo con un *Console.WriteLine*.

He revisado su codigo, y aqui es el codigo modificado con los errores coregido.
Puse `hiddenWord`, `letter`, y `secretWord` como argumentos de la funcion para que la funcion no accede variables fuera de si mismo.

```
static string changingHiddenWord(string hiddenWord, string letter, string secretWord)
{
    string changed, firstPart, endPart;

    int len = secretWord.Length;

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        string stri = Char.ToString(secretWord[i]);

        if (stri == letter)
        {
            changed = letter;

            // firstPart
            if (i == 0)
            {
                firstPart = "";
            }
            else
            {
                firstPart = hiddenWord.Substring(0, i);    
            }

            Console.WriteLine("firstPart: " + firstPart);
            Console.WriteLine("changed: " + changed);


            // endPart
            if (i == (len - 1))
            {
                // si 'i' esta igual a la indice ultima
                endPart = "";
            }
            else
            {
                endPart = hiddenWord.Substring(i + 1, len - 1 - i);
                // Chequear cuales son los valores de los argumentos de Substring
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("endPart => startIndex: {0}, length: {1}", i + 1, len - 1 - i));
            }

            Console.WriteLine("endPart: " + endPart);

            hiddenWord = firstPart + changed + endPart;
        }
    }

    return hiddenWord;
}
```

Puede llamar la funcion como esto:

```
string resultado = changingHiddenWord("------", "t", "fuente");
```

Answer (score 0):

Te pego aquí un ejemplo rápido de tu ahorcado. Fijate que string tiene un método que es indexof que te da posición de la letra que buscas.

```
//Por ejemplo 
posicion = hiddenWord.IndexOf('t');
//para la parte inicial que llamas 
firstPart = hiddenWord.Substring(0,posicion);
//para la final
endPart = hiddenWord.Substring(posicion+1,hiddenWord.Length-posicion-1)

class Program
{
    static string secretWord = "cocodrilo";
    static string hiddenWord = "";

    static List<char> letrasdescubiertas = new List<char>();
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        char[] aHiddenWord = new char[secretWord.Length];
        for (int i=0;i<secretWord.Length;i++)
        {
            aHiddenWord[i] = '_';
        }
        hiddenWord = new string(aHiddenWord);
        while (hiddenWord.ToString() != secretWord)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Escribe una letra");
            var s = Console.ReadLine();
            if (changingHiddenWord(hiddenWord.ToString(), Convert.ToChar(s)))
                Console.WriteLine(hiddenWord);
        }

    }

    static bool changingHiddenWord(string word, char letter)
    {
        var posicionLetter = -1;
        int len = secretWord.Length - 1;
        if (letrasdescubiertas.Contains(letter)) return false;
        if (secretWord.Contains(letter.ToString()))
        {
            posicionLetter = secretWord.IndexOf(letter);
            Reconstruye(posicionLetter, word, letter);
        }
        //comprobamos si está otra vez
        while (secretWord.Substring(posicionLetter+1, secretWord.Length - posicionLetter-1).Contains(letter.ToString()))
        {
            posicionLetter += (secretWord.Substring(posicionLetter + 1, secretWord.Length - posicionLetter-1).IndexOf(letter))+1;
            Reconstruye(posicionLetter, hiddenWord, letter);
        }

        return (posicionLetter >= 0) ? true : false;
    }

    static void Reconstruye(int posicionLetter, string word, char letter)
    {
        string firstPart = "", endPart = "";
        firstPart = word.Substring(0, posicionLetter);
        endPart = word.Substring(posicionLetter+1, word.Length - posicionLetter-1);
        hiddenWord = firstPart + letter + endPart;
    }
}
```